# Installing VS emulator for android on windows server 2016 in Azure env

Tags: android

I have installed VS emulator for android in azure env. OS is windows server 2016 but unable to launch the virtual machine getting an error as, The emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running and the virtual Machine Management service failed to start the virtual machine 'VS emulator 10.1-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI tablet, because one of the Hyper-V component is not running.Not sure why I've installed hyper-v role on the server as well, let me know the solution if anyone has.
Thanks in advance.